# Pyspark create column based on maximum of multiple columns that match a certain condition in corresponding columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have a Pyspark dataframe with id and 3 columns representing code buckets.

```
col_buckets ["code_1", "code_2", "code_3"]
```

and 3 columns representing amounts for corresponding code buckets.

```
amt_buckets = ["code_1_amt", "code_2_amt", "code_3_amt" ]
```

Here is a pseudocode for what I am trying to do.

```
for el in ['01', '06', '07']
    df= df.withColumn("max_amt_{el}", max(df.select(max(**amt_buckets**) for corresponding col_indices of amt_buckets if ***any of col_buckets*** ==el)))
```

how would I accomplish this?

here is a dataframe example for this:

[image]

```
Primary_id  Code_1  Code_2  Code_3  Amt_1   Amt_2   Amt_3   Max_01  Max_07  Max_06
Xxxxx998    Null    01      04      2000    1000    100     1000    0       0
Xxxxx997    01      01      07      200     300     400     300     400     0
Xxxxx996    07      Null    Null    100     Null    Null    0       100     0
Xxxx910     Null    Null    Null    300     100     200     0       0       0
```

I am trying to get the max_01, max_07 and max_06 columns

Comment: Where do you get the list of 01,06,07 , is that a standard already defined variable?

Comment: yeah those are predefined codes we are looking for among a possible list of codes in the dataframe

Comment: Okay and can you also replace the image with text visual of the dataframe so that it can be copied. Thanks

Comment: sure. I updated the question to include it

Comment: why is Max_01 third row value 100? shouldnt it be 0, and 100 should be in Max_07 column for the same row? as Code_1 is 07 for that row

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi. Hi, thanks for your help, and yes it should be 100 for the 07 column, not 01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **`spark2.4+`**, you can try this.

```
df.show() #sample dataframe
#+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
#|Primary_id|Code_1|Code_2|Code_3|Amt_1|Amt_2|Amt_3|
#+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
#|  Xxxxx998|  null|    01|    04| 2000| 1000|  100|
#|  Xxxxx997|    01|    01|    07|  200|  300|  400|
#|  Xxxxx996|    07|  null|  null|  100| null| null|
#|   Xxxx910|  null|  null|  null|  300|  100|  200|
#+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dictionary = dict(zip(['Code_1','Code_2','Code_3'], ['Amt_1','Amt_2','Amt_3']))

df.withColumn("trial", F.array(*[F.array(F.col(x),F.col(y).cast("string"))\
                                          for x,y in dictionary.items()]))\
  .withColumn("Max_01",F.when(F.size(F.expr("""filter(trial,x-> exists(x,y->y='01'))"""))!=0,\
       F.expr("""array_max(transform(filter(trial, x-> exists(x,y-> y='01')),z-> float(z[1])))"""))\
             .otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
  .withColumn("Max_06",F.when(F.size(F.expr("""filter(trial,x-> exists(x,y->y='06'))"""))!=0,\
       F.expr("""array_max(transform(filter(trial, x-> exists(x,y-> y='06')),z-> float(z[1])))"""))\
             .otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
  .withColumn("Max_07",F.when(F.size(F.expr("""filter(trial,x-> exists(x,y->y='07'))"""))!=0,\
       F.expr("""array_max(transform(filter(trial, x-> exists(x,y-> y='07')),z-> float(z[1])))"""))\
             .otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
  .drop("trial").show(truncate=False)

#+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
#|Primary_id|Code_1|Code_2|Code_3|Amt_1|Amt_2|Amt_3|Max_01|Max_07|Max_06|
#+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
#|Xxxxx998  |null  |01    |04    |2000 |1000 |100  |1000  |0     |0     |
#|Xxxxx997  |01    |01    |07    |200  |300  |400  |300   |400   |0     |
#|Xxxxx996  |07    |null  |null  |100  |null |null |0     |100   |0     |
#|Xxxx910   |null  |null  |null  |300  |100  |200  |0     |0     |0     |
#+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Nice , i was thinking if this is possible with filter over array zip of a literal array column with another zip of code and amount column. Cant test now though :)

Comment: @anky true that was my first instinct too.. but instead of doing that i used array of array instead of array of structs(as with arrays_zip). similar logic but different data types i guess. if u do try it, feel free to post it

Comment: @anky i was also thinking of a way to make this dynamic using structs such that we dont have to do withColumn 3 times(assuming list of columns to add is provided), and just select `col.*` at the end. would b less verbose and cleaner.. will try when i can

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi could you briefly explain your approach? thanks

Comment: @algorythms ofc, so we start off by creating a column of list of lists where the 2nd dimension is [Code_1,Amt_1] etc, then we use higher order function filter to traverse the list, and filter out any [ [] ] whereever it does not match our 01(or7or6), then i flatten it to get [01,200,01,300], the filter out 01 from it to get [200,300]and then just take the max of that using array_max. the second filter might not be necesssary but i didnt know if there is a case where 07 or something could be greater than amount so diddnt want to take the risk.

Comment: thank you for your help. the solution works fine for the most part, but I'm a few cases @MohammadMurtazaHashmi thank you for the help. the solution works fine for most cases, but I'm seeing a few cases  when it is not returning the right results for max. for example, one of the 'trial' arrays generated for the work I'm doing for is: [['01', '250.0'], ['01', '1000.0'], ['24', '2726.6666666666665'], ['24', '1000.0'], [None, '0.0']] ..however I'm getting 250 under max_01 instead of 1000.

Comment: let me know if you need me to provide an example of that row

Comment: i got it, it was a minor issue with string and array_max, I will update here and post on ur other question too.

Comment: check my updated solution, used transform to ensure we converted strings to numeric

Comment: Hi, this line runs fine in jupyter notebook but am getting a syntax error when running spark-submit from the terminal. Do you know what could be causing this?                                        df.withColumn("trial", F.array(*[F.array(F.col(x),F.col(y).cast("string"))\
                                          for x,y in dictionary.items()]))\

Comment: It could be the backward slash I was using to escape the line , try it without the slash before for x,y